# 5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: javascript, react-native

when i try to run app with xCode and npx react-native run-android i will fetch this error

use_flipper!({ "Flipper-DoubleConversion" => "3.1.7" })
and  use_flipper!({ "Flipper-DoubleConversion" => "1.1.7" })
and dead code Yes

Answer (score 0):

problem solve i am using rn-fetch-blob and react-native-blob-util same time then i remove rn-fetch-blob and my problem solve